# How can I get specific Request Attributes?

Tags: java, servlets

So right now I have code that will display the from the url:

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:9080/MyWebApp/MyServlet?qty=1&item=100&desc=CD+ROMS&price=9.99&action=add&addToCart=Add+to+cart
```

**What is shown:**

```
    Recent Queries
    Item_100
```

And here is the code that will display that:

```
public String getRecentQueries(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String queries = "";
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
       if (session != null)
       {
          Enumeration e = session.getAttributeNames();
          if ( e.hasMoreElements() )
          {
             queries += "<h4>Recent Queries</h4><ul>";
          }
          while ( e.hasMoreElements() )
          {
             String name = (String) e.nextElement();
             String value =
                (String) session.getAttribute(name);
             queries += "<li><a href=\"" + value + "\">" + 
                name + "</a></li>";
          }
          queries += "</ul></p>";
       }
       return queries;
}
```

My question is, given the values in the url, how do I get something other than just '`item`'? How would I get `desc`, or `price`?

Comment: Dude, You're trying to get the REQUEST-query-parameters out of the SESSION? I guess you're looking for <link href="http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29">HttpServletRequest.getQueryString</link> but you found the session parameters first (simply because they come first in the class doco), and that sounded close-enough (to a servlet noob), right? Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  You need to be pulling the parameter names and values directly from the request, not the attributes from the session.

```
public String getRecentQueries(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String queries = "";
    Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames();

    if ( e.hasMoreElements() )
    {
        queries += "<h4>Recent Queries</h4><ul>";
    }

    while ( e.hasMoreElements() )
    {
        String name = (String) e.nextElement();
        String value = (String) request.getParameter(name);
        queries += "<li><a href=\"" + value + "\">" + name + "</a></li>";
    }
    queries += "</ul></p>";

    return queries;
}
```